# Bad performance when drawing bitmap to canvas on SurfaceView with rotated matrix.

Tags: android, surfaceview

I use surface view to implement `image viewer`.
It works fine. But on some devices like htc new one , I got a bad performance.

I use a matrix to maintain what the image should show. (include translate ,scale , rotate).

And draw it with:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mMainBitmap, mImageMatrix, mMainBitmapPaint);
```

If `mImageMatrix`'s degree is 0 or 180 , the method test on `Htc` new One would cost around 5-10 ms. But other degree would cost 20-25 ms. But on `Acer` S1 it always cost 5-10 ms. And sometimes I need to draw many images at the same time , so I got a bad performance.

I think this is a device problem. But I wonder if there is any way to solve it.

Comment: What versions of Android run on these devices and can you post the whole of you `onDraw()` method?

Comment: Acer S1 is 4.2.2 and Htc new One is 4.4.2.

Comment: Sorry I can't post all my onDraw method. But the cost time what I say is only canvas.drawBitmap(mMainBitmap, mImageMatrix, mMainBitmapPaint). And I have removed other code in onDraw method for profile performance.

Answer (score 0):

What about having hardwareAcclerated flag in the AndroidManifest.xml?